# How does Transferwise work when the cash flows are unequal?

Tags: money-transfer, international-transfer

How does Transferwise work?

My understanding is that Transferwise owns bank accounts with local currencies in multiple countries, and the users pay into these accounts and are paid from another account in another country. My question is how would this work when the currency flows are heavily unbalanced, I read somewhere that the cash transfers from the US to Mexico is around 20x the transfers in the other direction.

In these cases, the rate advertised on Transferwise (the mid market exchange rate) is not the rate at which they can buy the currency on the markets, so I was wondering how they deal with this problem.

Comment: This is the exact question I have also in my mind. Another question is how does Transferwise pay salary to their employees? I mean they have to eventually withdraw or transfer some part of their profit from other accounts to local banks in EUR. How do they transfer it without using external services? Let's assume they don't always have enough profit in local account either, so they have to balance money.